# styling and positioning string of php with css

Tags: php, css, string, styles, location

I would like to know how to position string of php origin using css, I made a login form after logging in the users are directed to a dashboard where I would like to view their username in a particular location,

this is my code:

CSS

```
// font to decorate the username string
@font-face {
    font-family: 'chunkfiveroman';
    src: url('chunkroman/chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: url('chunkroman/chunkfive-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('chunkroman/chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('chunkroman/chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('chunkroman/chunkfive-webfont.svg#chunkfiveroman') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

#postioner
{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = $username;
?>
```

also I would like to know how to stlye the `$username` with the css font. :)

Comment: You style the form in html, not the php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output HTML with an appropriate `<link>` to your CSS.

For ***example***:

```
<?php
$username = 'Bob';

echo <<<EOT
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
</head>

<body>
$username
</body>
EOT;
?>
```